# Accessing ApplicationState variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I was going through the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.140%29.aspx in order to create a variable that can tell the program if it's on a local environment or not.

So this is what I have in Global.asax.cs:

```
namespace website
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        ...
        Application["loc"] = false;
        if (Request.Headers["host"].Contains("localhost"))
        {
            Application["loc"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access the ApplicationState variables in a Model file like this:

```
if (Application["loc"] != null)
{
    bool loc = (bool)Application["loc"];
}
```

Which is exactly how it's specified in the documentation, I get an error:

> The Name Application does not exist in the current context.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.application(v=vs.110).aspx) is an instance level property defined on `HttpApplication`. You can't try to access it without an instance of `HttpApplication`.

A reference to the current `HttpApplication` can be fetched via static property [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) which will return an `HttpContext` object; this can [be further queried](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.applicationinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the actual `HttpApplication`,

for example

```
var myHttpApp = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
var appState = myHttpApp.Application;
```

You could also directly use [`HttpContext.Current.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a reference to the current `HttpApplicationState` object.

To fix your code, you could do something like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Application["loc"] != null)
{
    bool loc = (bool)(HttpContext.Current.Application["loc"]);
}
```

Comment: This worked, now I have another problem though where Request doesn't exist yet when Global.asax.cs is run. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah you should be doing that (analyzing headers) in your controller's action or maybe as a message handler / filter. Global.asax.cs is good for "global" actions; analyzing headers is not such an action since it will vary per request.

Comment: OK, that works, but will it run through that logic for every request when it's in the Controller. I'm trying to get it to just run at the very beginning, then be the same for all future requests.

Comment: yes, it will happen for every request. You could probably set a boolean flag or something to indicate whether this has happened and then query that. This doesn't seem terribly elegant though, services should try to stateless.

Comment: OK, do you know of any documentation I could read that could help me set up an elegant environmental variable?

Comment: Maybe use sessions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx